# Angular: Displaying selected row data in a dialog

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm working on an angular project and I am facing a problem getting data from a component and using it on another.
So, I have a `table.component` with a table of employees and a view details button
now on click on the view details a dialog popup opens which is the modal-dialog component
in the openModal() I already get the row data and open the modal but the problem is with displaying the selected row data into the modal.
this is the openModal button from the table component

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="openModal(row)" 
 mat-raised-button style="background-color: unset;">
   <app-modal-dialog *ngIf="isModalOpen" 
   [selectedRow]="selectedRow" (closeDialog)="closeModal()"></app-modal-dialog>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><!-- Font Awesome Pro 5.15.4 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) -->
         <path d="M48 32h352c26.51 0 48 21.49 48 48v352c0 26.51-21.49 48-48 48H48c-26.51 0-48-21.49-48-48V80c0-26.51 21.49-48 48-48zm140.485 355.515l123.029-123.029c4.686-4.686 4.686-12.284 0-16.971l-123.029-123.03c-7.56-7.56-20.485-2.206-20.485 8.485v246.059c0 10.691 12.926 16.045 20.485 8.486z"/>
      </svg>
                                  
</button>
```

already have an error in the openModal(row) : `'row' does not exist on type 'TableComponent'`.
this is part of the `table.component.ts`:

```
  selectedRow: any;

  selectRow(row: any) {
    if (this.selectedRow === row) {
      this.selectedRow = null;
    } else {
      this.selectedRow = row;
      console.log(this.selectedRow);
    }
  }

  isModalOpen = false;

  openModal(row: any): void {
    this.selectRow(row);
    this.isModalOpen = true;
  }

  closeModal(): void {
    this.isModalOpen = false;
  }
```

thanks for helping me

I can't find anything on Google or YouTube if someone has a video or an article on this that may help a lot.